# how to set a alert if there is no matches found in search in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am implementing a search functionality .I found a link it is working fine ..But one one issue is there it is not set a alert when there is no match found in page.Can you please tell me where is insert that alert .I debug no alert coming.
I done like that .match.length() ==0 then i show alert but it is not working can you please help ?

here is the link where i found code.
http://jsbin.com/umodoy/7/edit

```
var searchIndex = -1;
var searchTermOld ='';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.searchbox').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()===''){
      var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
    }
      searchIndex = -1;
      $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    searchTermOld = $(this).val();
  });
  $('.searchbox').on('keyup',function(){

    var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
    if($(this).val()===''){
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
    }
    if($(this).val() !== searchTermOld){
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
      searchIndex = -1;
      $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");                              
  }
  });
  $('.search').on('click',function(){
    if(searchIndex == -1){
      var searchTerm = $('.searchbox').val();
      searchAndHighlight(searchTerm);
    }
    else searchNext();
    if($('.match').length >1){
      $('.searchNext').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
  $('.searchNext').on('click',searchNext);

  $('.searchPrev').on('click',searchPrev);
});

function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches;
        var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
        $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches !==null && matches.length > 0) {
            var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
            $(selector).html(txt);
            searchIndex++;
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
           $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);

          return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
  return false;
}

function searchNext(){
  searchIndex++;
  if (searchIndex >= $('.match').length) searchIndex = 0;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}

function searchPrev(){
  searchIndex--;
  if (searchIndex < 0) searchIndex = $('.match').length - 1;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsbin.com/umodoy/29/edit

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches;
        var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
        $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches !==null && matches.length > 0) {
            var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
            $(selector).html(txt);
            searchIndex++;
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
           $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);

          return true;
        }else{ //added this else here
          alert('not found');
        }
      return false;
    }
  return false;
}
```

for scrolling problem **js**

Working Demo http://jsbin.com/umodoy/37/edit

replace scrolling code by this

```
if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $(window).height()-10){
    $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}
```

Comment: only one more issue that it scroll to much .If the match on the same page it also scroll.I think it scroll only when it below or above the page

Comment: you first add large data then search it scroll too much it look not good it scroll upto  the text..

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/umodoy/26)**
You can add it after the end of the if that returns true.

Like:

```
  return true;
    }
  alert('no matches!');
  return false;
```

This `if (matches !==null && matches.length > 0)` searches for match different from NULL and returns true, which makes the function stop. If that statement is not met/true, you can place the alert after that if.

Comment: scrolling issues it scroll too much..:(

Comment: @Rohit, how do you mean scroll? There is no scroll in the demo, just alert box that no matches found.

Comment: actually when searvh is found..it should go to only upto focus text

Comment: if the test is found in font (same page ).it should not scroll but it is scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Just check return value of searchAndHighlight if its false  show alert.

```
if(!searchAndHighlight(searchTerm))
    alert('No Matches Found.');
```